# Using Keras/sklearn with CalibratedClassifierCV from sklearn.calibration

Tags: keras, scikit-learn

Is it possible to use Keras model objects with CalibratedClassifierCV from sklearn.calibration?  Or is there another way to performa isotonic regression in sklearn/other python packages without having to pass it a model object.

I tried using the sklearn wrapper for Keras, but it didn't work.  [Here is the doc for the CalibratedClassifierCV class](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.calibration.CalibratedClassifierCV.html#sklearn.calibration.CalibratedClassifierCV).

Comment: how to use KerasClassifier with CalibratedClassifierCV: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70655813/10375049

Comment: Does this answer your question? [trying to callibrate keras model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70655055/trying-to-callibrate-keras-model)

Answer (score 2):

You can train an isotonic regression a posteriori, **after prediction**. Let `'file1'` be a csv containing your predictions `pred` and real observed events `obs` on a subset of data. Ideally, this subset has never been used before (not even in Keras training). Let `file2` contain the predictions you want to calibrate (Keras predictions for the test set).

```
    import pandas as pd
    from sklearn.isotonic import IsotonicRegression
    never_seen=pd.read_csv('file1') 
    uncalibrated=pd.read_csv('file2')   
    
    ir = IsotonicRegression( out_of_bounds = 'clip' )   
    ir.fit( never_seen.pred,never_seen.obs )
    p_calibrated = ir.transform( uncalibrated.pred )
```